System.Net.Http.Json is not taking Fields into account when serializing or deserializing to JSON
When trying to Serialize a model which has data stored in fields System.Net.Http.Json is outputting an empty JSON Object. It works only when I use property with getters and setters.
I tried looking into what's the difference between the two, but I couldn't find anything that might affect their serializability
Consider the following class
public class User
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public string Username;
    public string Email;
}

When trying to Serialize an object of this call through JsonSerializer.Serialize we get {} as the output
var user = new User()
{
    Id = 12,
    Name = "user",
    Username = "username",
    Email = "user@email.com"
};

var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(user);
Console.WriteLine(jsonString);

Only when I update the User model to use properties with getters and setters JsonSerializer.Serialize works as expected.
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name {g et; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

After this change, we get the following output
{"Id":12,"Name":"user","Username":"username","Email":"user@email.com"}
HttpClient and HttpContent extension methods
Following the above MSDN tutorial and converted the properties to fields and it broke the deserialization as well in this case.

Not serializing fields is expected behavior.  Are you just looking for something like this?

Okay Thanks! This makes sense since I recently upgraded my project from .NET framework 4.8 to .NET 8 hence I am seeing this change in serialization
